# How to understand PHP Parser Generator grammar rule

Tags: php, parsing, lexer, parser-generator

I want to make a parser/lexer that will compile my template engine. I'm using [PHP_ParserGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_ParserGenerator) and [PHP_LexerGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_LexerGenerator). As explained in their document, I have created a lexer and that one is working. But when try to write a parser, I have not yet understood their document. I read the Lemon parser document, but my code still doesn't work. :(

I found [this example](http://blog.oncode.info/2007/10/25/eine-eigene-programmiersprache-erschaffen-lexer-und-parser-in-php/) containing "Hello world" of lexer/parser and I read parser/lexer of XenForo, vBulletin, Smarty. In the "Hello world" example it is simple, but when I try to group grammar rules like it is done in Xenforo `TAG_OPEN tag_attributes TAG_SELF_CLOSE` my parser doesn't work correctly.

```
 /*   0 */ "start ::= in",
 /*   1 */ "in ::= in PLAIN_TEXT",
 /*   2 */ "in ::= in curly",
 /*   3 */ "in ::= in tag",
 /*   4 */ "in ::= in TAG_COMMENT",
 /*   5 */ "in ::= in TAG_CLOSE",
 /*   6 */ "in ::=",
 /*   7 */ "tag ::= TAG_OPEN tag_attributes TAG_SELF_CLOSE",
 /*   8 */ "tag ::= TAG_OPEN tag_attributes TAG_END",
 /*   9 */ "tag_attributes ::= tag_attributes TAG_ATTRIBUTE DOUBLE_QUOTE quoted_inner DOUBLE_QUOTE",
 /*  10 */ "tag_attributes ::= tag_attributes TAG_ATTRIBUTE SINGLE_QUOTE quoted_inner SINGLE_QUOTE",
```

This is the y file of Smarty: [smarty_internal_templateparser.y](http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3758/branches/Smarty3Dev/development/lexer/smarty_internal_templateparser.y)

Can you please help me understand how I can group grammar rules the same way as Xenforo does?

This is [Lemon Parser document](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html)

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig Thank you for rewrite my post to english correctly

Comment: You are not getting a response, because your question is unclear.  You appear to be having a problem with writing grammar rules.  You have not provided any detail as to what grammar rules you did write (show us the code) or why they fail (or at least the output from some tool that you are interpreting as failure).  A hint: grammar rules don't need to be grouped to work properly; they are independent of order.   Grammar rule *content* has to be ordered in the expected order of encountering the entities.   And of course, y you might play with the working Xenforo example a bit.  Your move.